# c# app can't find dll in its working directory

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, reference

I just switched from C++ to C# and I am a bit confused about referencing DLLs.

I have a third party DLL and a simple testing application that uses some of its methods. When I compile the project, everything goes well, but when I run the compiled app on another computer, I've got an error that says that the DLL is missing even though the DLL is in the app's working directory. What's even more strange is that I have access to the source code of another app that is dependent on an older version of this DLL and this app works well.

I've gone through the code and all the solution settings without finding anything really different.

Can you tell me how to reference a `.dll` from a working dir (Visual Studio 2010)?

---

Below is the exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled

Message=Could not load file or assembly 'TIS.Imaging.ICImagingControl32, Version=3.2.4.1146, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257805929e8b7928' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source=ICtestapp

FileName=TIS.Imaging.ICImagingControl32, Version=3.2.4.1146, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257805929e8b7928

FusionLog=WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.

To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.

Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

 StackTrace:
      at ICtestapp.Form1.InitializeComponent()
      at ICtestapp.Form1..ctor()
      at ICtestapp.Program.Main()
 InnerException:
```

Comment: What's the .dll?  Is ist a third party component?  Some of the third party components require older COM objects to be installed because their .NET objects are merely wrappers around COM objects.  (IBM's ibm.data.db2.iseries.dll comes to mind - it needs Client Access installed.)  There could be a number of causes for this behavior  Also, the exact error on the client would help.  Finally, is this a Winforms app, ASP.NET, Console App, Windows Service, WPF... The more details you can share, the more likely we'll be able to help.

Comment: Yes, it is a third party .NET component - ICImagingControl (v3.2). The app is Windows forms. I'll post the error within an hour, I am not at the proper PC.

Comment: OK.  I know nothing about that control, but I looked it up and found their website, and I see the make an ActiveX and OCX controls (If I remember right, these are just other names for COM) in addition to the .NET controls.  That doesn't necessarily mean anything, but it wouldn't surprise me if the .NET control is a wrapper around their ActiveX control.  I'm actually on my way out the door.  Hopefully you get a good answer and I'm not leading you down a wrong trail.

Comment: exception description is long, see edit

Answer (score 1):

You have to [add the dll as reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in your project references, once you added the library in the reference, when you compile the program the dll will be automatically copied to the compilation output folder unless otherwise specified in the reference properties ...

Then if you copy all items that you will find in the compilation output folder in the new location in the other PC, you should not have any problems.

Check also that the .NET framework installed on the other machine is at least as the same level of the project target ..

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when you copy the debug executables over to another machine.  Try compiling in release and moving over.

Comment: Can you be more specific? This doesn't appear to answer the question.

Comment: I have seen this happen as well - Debug executables do not work on another machine (failing with a Missing DLL error) whereas Release ones do!  I have no idea why.